# Old PS1 Gaming on a PS2?

Tags: ps2, ps1

Are all the PS2 thick backwards compatible or was it just the early models? I had a first gen (bought when the concele was first released) PS2, but it finally died after all these long years. So I got me a new to me one, when I went to play some of my old PS1 games, it said disk error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PS2 of any version is compatible with all PS1 games (there are rare exceptions). Most probably it's just a technical problem with either disk and/or console itself. The PS2 is also known for it's [disk error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_2#Disc_Read_Error_.28DRE.29_lawsuit) problem, quote:

> A class action lawsuit was filed against Sony Computer Entertainment
>   America Inc. on July 16, 2002, in the Superior Court of California,
>   County of San Mateo. The lawsuit addresses consumer reports of
>   inappropriate "no disc error" (disc read error) messages and other
>   problems associated with playing DVDs and CDs on the PlayStation 2.
>
> Sony settled its "disc read error" lawsuit by compensating the
>   affected gamers with USD $25, a free game from a specified list, and
>   the reduced cost repair or replacement (at SCEA's discretion) of the
>   damaged system. This settlement was subject to the courts' approval,
>   and hearings began in the US and Canada on April 28, 2006, and May 11,
>   2006, respectively.

But I'm not sure that "slim" models are affected with mentioned above problems.